# How to reorder the bookmarks on the home page, including the folders in Safari?

Tags: safari, web-browser, bookmarks

How to reorder the bookmarks on the home page, including the folders in Safari? The sort-by is not shown in the main list of bookmarks.

I can reorder the bookmarks in a folder but not on the main page.

Comment: Are you talking about Safari bookmarks?

Comment: If you are talking about the preference that allows you to open a new page in Safari (tab or new window) which is called "Start Page" there is no way to *move* anything around or *change* anything. You can select what items you want to see but not what those items contain.

Comment: Yes, Safari bookmarks